# change the baseurl after the location change

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I had been using the url something like this: `http://something.com/project` and I was using `$this->baseurl;` which was working fine but after transferring from `http://something.com/project` to `http://www.project.com` the baseurl is not working. So I think I should change the base link but I have no idea on how to do?

---

Before change the base url is project. After change the base url is www.project.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently set this and worked:

```
$this->baseurl = JURI::root();
```

But I don't think it's good idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **$live_site** variable in **configuration.php** file to:

```
public $live_site = 'www.project.com';
```

Comment: What Joomla version are you using? Are you trying to use $this->baseurl; in your template, or somewhere else?

Comment: joomla 2.5 and $this->baseurl in template

Comment: The need to use $live_site is extremely rare.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure if template stores path in it's params... Worth a try anyway :)